# Steer Suite Installation errors

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2017, glew, freeglut

I am trying to install Steer Suite onto my PC using Visual Studio 2017.  I have placed all the header, DLL, and lib into the correct places from Free Glut and GLEW.  I have cloned Steer Suite form Github and when I try to compile the Steer Suite Solution I get C1083 errors.  Cannot fine GL/glew.h
Here is a list of files and where I have put them.

> header files: glut.h, freeflut_std.h, freeglut_ext.h, freeglut.h
>
> into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Include\GL
>
> 32 bit lib file: freeglut.lib
>
> into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\lib
>
> 64 bit lib file: freeglut.lib
>
> into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\lib\x64
>
> 32 bit dll file: freeglut.dll
>
> into C:\Windows\SysWOW64
>
> 64 bit dll file: freeglut.dll
>
> into C:\Windows\System32

for the GLEW files I placed

> glew32.dll
>
> into C:\Windows\System32
>
> glew32.lib
>
> into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\lib
>
> glew.h
>
> into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Include\GL
>
> wglew.h
>
> into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Include\GL

[image: error list]

Comment: I would not have put files into the Visual Studio folders or the windows system folders.

Comment: This is what my instructions were.  How should I do?

Comment: 1. Install these in your own location somewhere on your hard drive. 2. Add an entry in the c++ setting `Additional Include Directories` setting to the folder containing GL. Make sure you apply this to all configurations. 3. Add each .lib to linker dependencies for each configuration. Be careful if there are separate libs for Debug and Release. 4. Put the dll in the same folder as your application's executable ( again if there are separate .dlls for release and debug make sure you copy the Debug one to the Debug folder and the Release one to the Release folder.

Comment: The following part: **Add each .lib to linker dependencies for each configuration** is done from the Linker->General->Additional Dependencies setting in your projects settings (I was typing on a linux box / had to check the exact wording in VS).

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers.  I actually solved the problem by installing the software package in Ubuntu 14.04.  I could not get the software to work on any other Linux Distro.  In any case, it runs on Ubuntu 14.04.  I'll try the suggestions here when i get a chance.